# How to solve the Diophantine equation: $x^3 + y^3 + xy = 223$ for all integer pairs $(x,y)$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have tried factorizing, inequality bounds and any standard technique I could, but somehow nothing seems to work. I know one solution is $(1,6)$ and $(6,1)$, but that was through trial and error. How to do it "mathematically"?

Comment: Usually, diophantine equations are very difficult to solve completely. Not sure whether methods using elliptic or hyperelliptic curves help here. What was your search range ?

Comment: $[-6, 6]$ and then trying to figure out $y$ for corresponding $x$

Comment: @Peter  if you graph it you see that $0 < x+y < 1$   unless $ |x|, |y|  < 12 $  Indeed, if $y = 1-x,$    we get $x^3 + xy + y^3  = 2x^2 - 2x +1$  so $x= 11$  gives $221$  while $x=12$ gives $265$

Comment: oh, if $x+y = 0$   we get  $x^3 + xy + y^3  $  coming out to $-x^2,$  so the curve always has $x+y > 0.$   If $ \delta > 0$   and $x+y+ \delta = 0$ then the cubic comes out as $-\left( (1+3 \delta)x^2 + \delta (1+\delta)x + \delta^3 \right)$   which has discriminant $ \delta^2 (1+3 \delta) (1-\delta)  $

Answer (score 5):

Number theoretic solution.

Let $x+y=u$, $xy=v$. Then $u^3-3uv+v=223$, which solves out $v=\dfrac{u^3-223}{3u-1}$. $9v\in\mathbb Z$ implies $3u-1\mid27u^3-6021$. Since $$3u-1\mid(3u)^3-1^3=27u^3-1,$$ also $3u-1\mid6020$.

Let $3u-1=k$ to have $u=\dfrac{k+1}3$, $v=\dfrac{\left(\frac{k+1}3\right)^3-223}k$. Notice that $u^2-4v=(x-y)^2\ge0$. By doing simple approximation, this doesn't hold for $k<0$ and starts to fail when $k\ge29$. So we only look at the small factors and get
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|}\hline
u&v\\\hline\hline
1 & -111 \\
2 & -43 \\
5 & -7 \\
7 & 6 \\\hline
\end{array}$$
By checking whether $u^2-4v$ is a perfect sqaure, we find $(7,6)$ is the only possibility. Since $\begin{cases}x+y=7;\\xy=6.\end{cases}$ imply $(x,y)=(1,6)$ or $(6,1)$, they're our only solutions.

---

Full results of $(u,v)$ by python listed below. But using my solution above you don't need software at all.
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|}\hline
u&v\\\hline\hline
0 & 223 \\
1 & -111 \\
-1 & 56 \\
2 & -43 \\
-2 & 33 \\
-3 & 25 \\
5 & -7 \\
7 & 6 \\
-9 & 34 \\
12 & 43 \\
-14 & 69 \\
-23 & 177 \\
29 & 281 \\
47 & 740 \\
-57 & 1078 \\
72 & 1735 \\
-100 & 3323 \\
-143 & 6801 \\
201 & 13489 \\
287 & 27488 \\
-401 & 53556 \\
502 & 84057 \\
-1003 & 335225 \\
2007 & 1342906 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, awesome solution! Sorry, I am new here so can't upvote, but this deserves an upvote.

Comment: @ArmaanHooda, I just upvoted it for you (but also because it's a neat solution).

Answer (score 2):

Let $s=x+y$ then
$$x^3 + (s-x)^3 +x(s-x)-223=0\Leftrightarrow (3s-1)x^2-s(3s-1)x+(s^3-223)=0.$$
The quadratic equation with respect to $x$ has discriminant:
$$\Delta=-(3 s-1)(s^3 + s^2 - 892)$$
which is $\geq 0$ just when the integer $s$ belongs to the interval $[1,9]$ (notice that the sign of the second factor is easy to find since its derivative is $s(3s+2)$).

Looking in that interval for perfect squares, we find just one value for $s$, i.e. $7$ with $\Delta=100^2$. Then
$$x=\frac{s(3s-1)\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2(3s-1)}=\frac{7\cdot 20 \pm100}{2\cdot 20}=1,6.$$
Hence the integer solutions $(x,y)$ are just $(1,6)$ and $(6,1)$.

Comment: Appreciate it, I tried this one but thought it to be somewhat tiresome. Nevertheless, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I am new to the platform, and can't vote yet, so that wasn't me! I think the solution is fantastic!

Comment: @RobertZ Perhaps it's becuse you didn't put up the complete solution before you edited, and somebody may think that it is not practical or something. But now it is nice and correct. 

Comment: @youthdoo Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ or $y=0$ it’s straightforward (no solutions).

If $x,y> 0$ it’s easy to simply search for solutions ($x^3 \leq 223$ so $x \leq 6$, same for $y$).

If $x,y < 0$, it’s easy enough as well: write $x=-a$, $y=-b$ with $a,b>0$, then $a^3+b^3-ab=-223$ thus $ab > a^3+b^3 \geq a^2+b^2$, contradiction.

If $y=-b, x=a$ with $a,b>0$ (by symmetry, the only remaining case), then the equation becomes $a^3=223+b^3+ab$, so $a > b$. Write $a=c+b$, then $3cb^2+3c^2b+c^3=223+b^2+cb$.

Because $2cb^2 \geq b^2+cb$, it follows that $cb^2+3c^2b+c^3 \leq 223$, in particular $c \leq 6$ and $b \leq 14$. Then you can brute force again for solutions.

Comment: Insightful solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was working on another solution (finally got it!), so thought it would be worthwhile to post for others to comment and give feedback.

In the equation, $a^3 + b^3 + ab = 223$ multiply both sides by 27. This gives
$(3a)^3 + (3b)^3 + 3\cdot(3a)\cdot(3b) = 6021.$

Now, let $3a = x, 3b = y$.

The equation now becomes: $x^3 + y^3 + (-1)^3 + 3\cdot(x)\cdot(y)\cdot(-1) = 6020$

Using the identity $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy- yz - zx)$,we can write the above equation this way:-

$(x + y − 1)((x + y)^2 + x + y + 1 − 3xy)  = 6020 = 2^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot43$

We can pretty much brute force our way to the answer now, and substitute $x$ for $\frac{a}{3}$ to get $(6,1)$ and $(1,6)$.